# Which version of Ruby is mintiest 5.14.1 gem compatible with?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, minitest

When I run:
$ bundle install

I get this response:
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
minitest-5.14.1 requires ruby version ~> 2.2, which is incompatible with the
current version, ruby 3.0.0p0

I only have ruby 3.0.0p0 installed.

[minitest gem page](https://rubygems.org/gems/minitest/versions/5.14.4) says:
Required ruby version >= 2.2, < 4.0

I assume this means anything up to Ruby 3.0.0p0 is compatible. However, that isn't what the error message says.

Comment: Install newer version of minitest (>= 5.14.3).

Note: This should work but running `bundle install` still produces the same error.

When I run `gem list` I only see minitest-5.14.4 (latest version). 

activesupport gem seems to have minitest as a dependency so maybe that is where the request for the older version is coming from. Not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a solution. I'd call it more of a work around.

1. Install ruby version 2.7.2
2. Update .ruby-version file in Jekyll to `2.7.2`

That's it :)

Ideal solution would include identifying why Jekyll was dependent on minitest-5.14.1 (when only 5.14.4 was installed based on `gem list`).